# rewriting urls in codeigniter

Tags: php, url, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite the following codeigniter url

```
localhost/test_project/pages/show_page/11
```

to

```
localhost/test_project/pages/11
```

and is it possible to further reduce like:

```
localhost/test_project/11
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please see "Setting your own routing rules" in http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit this file: `application/config/routes.php`.

Let's assume you have a `pages` controller and a `show_page` method with receives an id as a parameter (just as you said).

your URL is like `localhost/test_project/pages/show_page/11`

I assume that the parameter is always a number, so using wildcards as described [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) you can add the following to your `routes.php` file:

```
$route['pages/(:num)'] = "pages/show_page/$1";
```

So your URLs will be like `localhost/test_project/pages/3`. This is like saying if anyone tried to visit `localhost/test_project/pages/3`, he/she actually means `localhost/test_project/pages/show_page/3`.

For urls like `localhost/test_project/3` you can add this:

```
$route['(:num)'] = "pages/show_page/$1";
```

Answer (score 1):

You've a few [options](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html). These are in descending order of priority.

1. First there is `routes.php`, which is the generally preferred way of handling things (information already provided, but [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) it is again).
2. You can also add a _resolve method to a controller (which means that CI needs to get to your controller to begin with), and
3. finally you can override the CI_Router library, the class which actually returns the route to go to.

Seriously, don't override CI_Router unless you know what you're doing.